# How to render multiple dynamic options into select box in React from Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, axios

I have a perplexing question.  I am receiving a payload from an axios call that I need to populate in a select (dropdown) box in React--except the payload I receive is an array of arrays.  There is a large array of (2) Two element arrays received, the two elements being a shorthand ID name, and the fullname. I need to concatenate these two values together into one option.  For instance the structure of the data received:

```
{
   "groups": [
      [
        "short_name_id",
        "longer_name"
      ]
]
```

The data in the select box should be a concatenation of the two elements like: "short_name_id - longer_name" I don't think I have to manually concatenate both the two values together and then put in state, but to show each of them together in each select dropdown choice.

In the call I have an axios call that returns the data correctly:

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('https://someurl.com/api/groups')
      .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
         this.setState({ data: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
}
```

In the render() I set the props to the data object returned but the select box doesn't populate?
Not sure how to get the two array elements to show up as one entry and populate the state into the select box?  I am not accessing/referencing the data that is in state properly considering the array structure I don't think?

```
render() {
   const { groups } = this.props;
      return (
         <label>
           Group:
              <select onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
              {groups &&
                groups.length > 0 &&
                groups.map(group => {
                return <option key={group} value={group}>{group}</option>;
               })}
              </select>
          </label>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
   const { groups } = this.props;
      return (
         <label>
           Group:
              <select onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
              {groups &&
                groups.length > 0 &&
                groups.map(group => {
                return <option key={group[0]} value={group[0]}>{group[0]} - {group[1]}</option>;
               })}
              </select>
          </label>
      );
}
```

This should work, but personally I wouldn't store the data as array of arrays. I would rather store them as array of objects, so instead of looking like this:

```
[
  "short_name_id",
  "longer_name"
]
```

It would look like this:

```
{
  "short_name_id": "value here",
  "longer_name": "value here"
}
```

This way your return statement instead of looking like this:

```
return <option key={group[0]} value={group[0]}>{group[0]} - {group[1]}</option>;
```

could look like this:

```
return <option key={group.short_name_id} value={group.short_name_id}>{group.short_name_id} - {group.longer_name}</option>;
```